# Data connection import problems

Tags: vba, excel

I am still kinda new to VBA, and I am having a little issue. I have a data connection setup, and the import pulls all of the data from the table. The problem that I am running into is that third columns contains a number that is 16 digits long. When the import happens, I need this column to be imported as a text field, otherwise the import replaces the last digit with a 0. Here is the code for my import. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Worksheets("Equip Related").Visible = True
    Dim WK As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Feedback").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Feedback"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;WEB ADDRESS HERE", Destination:= _
        Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "feedbacklog"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the results from your querytabel in a resultsobject and set the datatype of each column:

```
Set myResults = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;WEB ADDRESS HERE", Destination:= _
    Range("$A$1"))

With myResults
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes := _ 
        Array(xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlTextFormat) 
    .Refresh 
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I attempted to add this to my code, but i am getting a Compile error: Expected Expression on this part:

'.TextFileColumnDataTypes := _ 
        Array(xlGeneralFormat, xlGeneralFormat, xlTextFormat)'

I am not sure why this is happening or exactly how to correct it.